# How to add a /api/v1/ prefix to uri in spring cloud gateway?

Tags: regex, spring, spring-cloud-gateway

I have two services and a gateway working with eureka:

user-service running on 8081

health-service running on 8082

So far I tried this:

```
routes:
        - id: user-service-route
          uri: http://localhost:8081/user-service
          predicates:
            - Path=/user-service/**
          filters:
            - RewritePath=(?<serviceName>.*), /api/v1/{serviceName}
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prefix location for all microservices if you use load balancer:

```
server:
  port: 8765

management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: gateway

eureka:
  client:
    service-url:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka

spring:
  application:
    name: gateway
  cloud:
    gateway:
      discovery:
        locator:
          enabled: true
          lower-case-service-id: true
      default-filters:
        - RewritePath=/api/v1/.*?/(?<remaining>.*), /$\{remaining}
      routes:
        - predicates:
            - Path=/api/v1/profile/**
          uri: lb://profile
        - predicates:
            - Path=/api/v1/dictionary/**
          uri: lb://dictionary
```

Answer (score 2):

try

```
filters:
        - RewritePath=(?<serviceName>.*), /api/v1/$\{serviceName}
```